# rubocop cops disagree: Layout/EmptyLineAfterGuardClause vs Layout/TrailingWhitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

`Ruby 2.6.5`
`Rails 5.2.3`

When I ran `rubocop app/models/foo.rb`, I got:

```sh
app/models/foo.rb:24:5: C: Layout/EmptyLineAfterGuardClause: Add empty line after guard clause.
    return false if new_record?
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

So I made the change:

```rb
# before
def readonly?
  return false if new_record?
  bars.any?
end

#after
def readonly?
  return false if new_record?

  bars.any?
end
```

And got:

```sh
app/models/foo.rb:25:1: C: Layout/TrailingWhitespace: Trailing whitespace detected.

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

Fixing one triggered the other and vice-versa forever.

If I want this file to pass rubocop and be good in terms of Ruby/Rails way, which cop is best to ignore?

Comment: Does that new line between have any white space created by automatic indentation of the editor? if so, remove it

Comment: Not a big rubocop fan, I can imagine it has its use in a big team. As the answer stated: you probably have spaces on the empty line, which might be an editor setting. Not really something I would want to invest time in. Also, I actually prefer your `before` so I would probably ignore the `EmptyLineAfterGuardClause` rule. Alternatively, I would even be tempted to write `new_record? ? false : bars.any?`. I do not really see the need for the "quick" exit here? (but of course this all is a matter of taste)

Comment: @nathanvda, That's a great suggestion. Thank you! I don't use one line statements as often as I probably should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress `TrailingWhitespace` cop remove any space or tab in the line between `return false if new_record?` and  `bars.any?`:

```rb
def readonly?
  return false if new_record?

  bars.any?
end
```

Trailing whitespace [`\s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) is any space, tab, carriage return at the end of a line, without any other characters following it.